# Using Nullish Coaleshing Operator

Tags: javascript

The program goes through the days and prints the opening and closing hours for each day. On saturday the situation is different, there is no PM times. So by using `??` I thought the program could switch to the second sentence as on Saturday `{openPM}` and `{closePM}` are `undefined`,but it does not work.

```js
const weekdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];


const  openingHours = {

    [weekdays[1]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[2]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[3]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[4]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[5]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        //openPM: 0,
        //closePM: 0,
    }
}

const entries = Object.entries(openingHours)

for (let [day, {openAM, closeAM, openPM, closePM}] of entries)
console.log(`the store is open on ${day} from ${openAM} to ${closeAM} and from ${openPM} to ${closePM}` ?? `the store is open on ${day} from ${openAM} to ${closeAM} `)
```

Comment: what result do you want?

Comment: the store is open on tue from 9 to 12 and from 15 to 20
the store is open on wed from 9 to 12 and from 15 to 20
the store is open on thu from 9 to 12 and from 15 to 20
the store is open on fri from 9 to 12 and from 15 to 20
the store is open on sat from 9 to 12

Comment: please check the working on [Nullish Coalescing opeator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). The left parameter needs to be `undefined` or `null` to see it in action, which is never happening in your case. You left hand argument will always have a templated string. You can use a ternary(`?`) operator instead

Comment: @Salvino TThank you for that. So just one `undefined` parameter among other truely parameters will not turn all the argument `undefined?

Comment: No sir. That's not how string templating works. Only that particular parameter interpolated between the string will be null/undefined. Hence the left hand parameter will still have the rest of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first template string cannot be `null` thus your nullish operator can never be in action. So in your case, you probably don't want to use `??` but the ternary operator `? :` to decide which string template to output

```js
const weekdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];


const  openingHours = {

    [weekdays[1]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[2]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[3]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[4]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        openPM: 15,
        closePM: 20,
    },
    [weekdays[5]]: {
        openAM: 9,
        closeAM: 12,
        //openPM: 0,
        //closePM: 0,
    }
}

const entries = Object.entries(openingHours)

for (let [day, {openAM, closeAM, openPM, closePM}] of entries) {
  let oh = (openPM && closePM)
     ? `the store is open on ${day} from ${openAM} to ${closeAM} and from ${openPM} to ${closePM}`
     : `the store is open on ${day} from ${openAM} to ${closeAM} `
  console.log(oh)
}
```

Comment: @derpirsher Thank you for the input.  What do you mean by saying 'Your first template string cannot be `null`' ?

Comment: @Matteo A string is never `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: you do a `console.log(\`foo ${bar} baz\` ?? \`bla ${blubb} boing\`)`. Here the first string (ie the one before the `??`) can never be null, because, well, it's a template string with content. But the [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator only returns the second part (ie the thing after `??`) if the first part is null. Which, again, can't be in your case ...

Comment: @derpirscher understood, thanks. But mine contains for Saturday 2 `undefined` values, that's what I do not get..

Comment: Yeah, two of the "placeholders" may be undefined. But that doesn't make the whole string undefined. Why would it? Well the result will contain the string `"undefined"` but that has nothing to do with a value being `undefined` (ie not set to anything)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an array for the openings hours?

```js
const
    weekdays = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'],
    openingHours = {
        [weekdays[1]]: [{ open: 9, close: 12 }, { open: 15, close: 20 }],
        [weekdays[2]]: [{ open: 9, close: 12 }, { open: 15, close: 20 }],
        [weekdays[3]]: [{ open: 9, close: 12 }, { open: 15, close: 20 }],
        [weekdays[4]]: [{ open: 9, close: 12 }, { open: 15, close: 20 }],
        [weekdays[5]]: [{ open: 9, close: 12 }]
    };

for (const [day, openings] of Object.entries(openingHours))
console.log(`the store is open on ${day}${openings.map(({ open, close }) => ` from ${open} to ${close}`).join(' and')}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole string wont evaluated to null based only of the `openPM` and `closePM` being undefined. You need to set and handle the state to evaluate te check if its opened in the afternoon.

```
  for (let [day, {openAM, closeAM, openPM, closePM}] of entries) {
  const opensMorning = !!openAM && !!closeAM;
  const opensAfternoon = !!openPM && !!closePM;
  console.log(opensMorning, opensAfternoon);
  const logString = opensAfternoon ? 
    `the store is open on ${day} from ${openAM} to ${closeAM} and from ${openPM} to ${closePM}` :
    `the store is open on ${day} from ${openAM} to ${closeAM} `
  console.log(logString);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

@Matteo, Attaching an example here, so that you clearly understand why the nullish coalescing operator is not working for you. Try running the snippet below. **Your full string will never be null even if one or more of the parameters are `undefined` within the string tempate**.

##### Solution:

Use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator instead.

```js
let name = "Matteo";
let job;

console.log(`Hello world! My name is ${name} and I work as ${job}`);

// You'll have to use this instead. 
console.log(job ? `Hello world! My name is ${name} and I work as ${job}`: `Hello world! My name is ${name} and I'm jobless` );
```

Comment: I thought that at least one `undefined` parameter would turn the string `undefined`, but now I understand it does not.But why does not turn `undefined`, even if there are `undefined` elements in it? Anyway, thank you for taking the time to explain